# What does NF resistor value mean?

Tags: resistors, schematics

I have a schematic I am looking at:

[image]

What does the NF on the resistor mean?

Answer (score 3):

Not populated — don't put any resistor there. Or in the case of whoever wrote this schematic, "not fitted" or something like that.

As the doc says, this is a spot where you can put a pi network, but with the R1 and R3 footprints unpopulated, and R2 0-ohm, you get a "direct" (no matching network) connection between LTE_ANT and J1.

Comment: What is the point to putting a resistor that you should not place in the schematic? Why not just leave it out?

Comment: Somewhat curious that they'd call these "R1, R2, R3", where the intended PI matching network (if needed) would be populated with "C1, L2, C3".

Comment: @Trev347 Because if you want to change the frequency response of the filter, you may want to put something there.

Comment: @glen_geek agreed. It doesn't seem very carefully done. I understand R2 since it's populated with 0R, but it's still unclear. But I don't see how the intent could be anything else :)